# I want to sort data present in excel file in sheet with respect to column. (The excel file has multiple sheets)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, sorting, xlrd

[Excel Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3Zmo.png)
This is the data I've in an excel file. There are 10 sheets containing different data and I want to sort data present in each sheet by the 'BA_Rank' column in descending order.
After sorting the data, I've to write the sorted data in an excel file.
(for eg. the data which was present in sheet1 of the unsorted sheet should be written in sheet1 of the sorted list and so on...)

If I remove the heading from the first row, I can use the pandas (sort_values()) function to sort the data present in the first sheet and save it in another list.
like this

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

doc = xlrd.open_workbook('without_sort.xlsx')
xl = pd.read_excel('without_sort.xlsx')
length = doc.nsheets
#print(length)

#for i in range(0,length):
#sheet = xl.parse(i)

result = xl.sort_values('BA_Rank', ascending = False)
result.to_excel('SortedData.xlsx')
print(result)
```

So is there any way I can sort the data without removing the header file from the first row?
and how can I iterate between sheets so as to sort the data present in multiple sheets?

(Note: All the sheets contain the same columns and I need to sort every sheet using 'BA_Rank' in descending order.)

Answer (score 0):

First input, you don't need to call `xlrd` when using `pandas`, it's done under the hood.

Secondly, the `read_excel` method its REALLY smart. You can (imo should) define the sheet you're pulling data from. You can also set up lines to skip, inform where the header line is or to ignore it (and then set column names manually). Check the docs, it's quite extensive.

If this "10 sheets" it's merely anecdotal, you could use something like `xlrd` to extract the workbook's sheet quantity and work by index (or extract names directly).

The sorting looks right to me.

Finally, if you wanna save it all in the same workbook, I would use `openpyxl` or some similar library (there are many others, like `pyexcelerate` for large files).
This procedure pretty much always looks like:

1. Create/Open destination file (often it's the same method)
2. Write down data, sheet by sheet
3. Close/Save file

If the data is to be writen all on the same sheet, `pd.concat([all_dataframes]).to_excel("path_to_store")` should get it done

Comment: If I used read_excel and then access each sheet using sheet_by_index then the code looks like this.
`
sheet = doc.sheet_by_index(0)
result = sheet.sort_values('BA_Rank', ascending = False)
`
But the kernal is showing an error.. The error is 'Sheet' object has no attribute 'sort_values'

What to do in that case?

(P.S: if you can write the code then it'll be very helpful for me...)
Thank you

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html